# ASP.NET Entity Framework, if empty string - contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have query like this:

```
var listAds = (from a in _db.Ads
                           where 
                           a.Animal.Contains(animal) &&
                           a.AnimalBreed.Contains(breed) &&
                           GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(a.X, a.Y, 51.919438, 19.145136) <= distance
                           select a).ToList();
```

If my string (breed or animal) is empty, then not find any record..

How to make it work even if the string is empty?

Thanks for reply, best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small addition to Kirill's answer:
Checks null (if would) values too.

Update:

Sorry "animal" doesnt exists.
it should be:

```
var listAds = (from a in _db.Ads
                           where 
                           (a.Animal.Contains(animal)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Animal)) &&                       (a.AnimalBreed.Contains(breed)||string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.AnimalBreed)) &&
                           GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(a.X, a.Y, 51.919438, 19.145136) <= distance
                           select a).ToList();
```

Comment: An unhandled exception has occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. :(

Comment: my animal is ?animal= - thats it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var listAds = (from a in _db.Ads
                           where 
                           (a.Animal.Contains(animal)||animal=="") &&
                           (a.AnimalBreed.Contains(breed)||animal=="") &&
                           GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(a.X, a.Y, 51.919438, 19.145136) <= distance
                           select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

> If my string (breed or animal) is empty, then not find any record..

then you could do like in the following snippet

```
var listAds = (from a in _db.Ads
                           where 
                           (animal != string.Empty && breed != string.Empty) &&
                           a.Animal.Contains(animal) &&
                           a.AnimalBreed.Contains(breed) &&
                           GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(a.X, a.Y, 51.919438, 19.145136) <= distance)
                           select a).ToList();
```